# How to project some of the embedded documents? Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a document as follows:

```
{"_id":{"$_id":"5dd315bc717872581c5071a8"},
"answered":[
         {"waiting":false,"_id":{"$_id":"5dd315fe717872581c5071a9"},"user":"5dd2f023b6c5075758c06cb5"}, 
         {"waiting":true,"_id":{"$_id":"5dd31605717872581c5071aa"},"user":"5dd2ed7ab6c5075758c06ca9"}, 
         {"waiting":true,"_id":{"$_id":"5dd31608717872581c5071ab"},"user":"5dd2ed97b6c5075758c06cab"}]
```

What is the query which will return to me only the documents where "waiting" is true?
i.e

```
{"_id":{"$_id":"5dd315bc717872581c5071a8"},
"answered":[
         {"waiting":true,"_id":{"$_id":"5dd31605717872581c5071aa"},"user":"5dd2ed7ab6c5075758c06ca9"}, 
         {"waiting":true,"_id":{"$_id":"5dd31608717872581c5071ab"},"user":"5dd2ed97b6c5075758c06cab"}]
```

Comment: Here are some examples on [querying any array of embedded documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/).

Comment: @DavidConway check with below answer